# LDAP: error code 1 - The directory server could not find a network group for the bind dn ""

Tags: oracle, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Am Developing an application in Spring MVC with Spring Security. Now Integrating the OUD (Oracle Unified Directory) through LDAP. User authentication is working perfectly but the response from the LDAP and OUD is 
[image]
Mapping between application and LDAP

```
<bean id="contextSource"
          class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldaps://192.196.0.182:1636/O=company"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
          class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider" >
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="in.web.service.impl.CustomLdapBindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
                <property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <list>
                        <value>cn={0},ou=groups</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="in.web.service.impl.CustomLdapUserAuthoritiesPopulator">
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>     
    </bean>
```

My observations

1. Since the application can able to find the users I assume configurations are correct
2. Since the LDAP error code is 1 (Is there any possibility for error in OUD setup)

Comment: please don't post text as images

Comment: Similar question was asked by @Aadhavan:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557016/ldap-empty-binddn-and-authentication-type-becomes-simple-from-none.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be, bind dn is missing.

bind dn is your admin account/a user with required permissions, which you use to communicate with OUD.

Your configuration does not have any traces of this.