# LDAP: Empty binddn"" and Authentication type becomes simple from none

Tags: oracle, spring-security, oracle11g, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Am Developing an application in Spring MVC & JPA with Spring Security. Now Integrating the OUD (Oracle Unified Directory) through LDAP. While User authentication the response from the LDAP in OUD log file is

**CONNECT** conn=909681 from ******* to *******:1636 protocol=LDAPS

**Bind REQ** conn=909681 op=0 msgID=1 **type=SIMPLE dn=""** version=3

**BindRES** conn=909681 op=0 msgID=1 result=1 message="The directory server could not find a network group for the bind dn "" because the client connection does not match the connection criteria for any network groups."

**DISCONNECT** conn=909681 reason="Client Disconnect"

Mapping between application and LDAP in security.xml file

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldaps://192.168.0.182:1636/o=company"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="cn=userid,o=company,ou=groups"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider" >
     <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="in.web.service.impl.CustomLdapBindAuthenticator">
               <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
               <property name="userDnPatterns">
                   <list>
                       <value>cn={0},ou=groups</value>
                   </list>
               </property>
           </bean>
     </constructor-arg>
     <constructor-arg>
           <bean class="in.web.service.impl.CustomLdapUserAuthoritiesPopulator">
           </bean>
     </constructor-arg>     
 </bean>
```

Code in CustomLdapBindAuthenticator

```
public LdapUserDetails search(String cn) throws Exception {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        String sp = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, sp);

        String [] urls = contextSource.getUrls();
        for(String url: urls){
            System.out.println("ldapurls="+url);
        }
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, urls[0]);

        DirContext dctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

        String base = "ou=groups,o=company";
        System.out.println("BASE DN="+base);

        SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
        String[] attributeFilter = {"cn", "fullName", "mail", "l", "mobile"};
        sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
        sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        String filter = "(&(cn="+cn+")(objectClass=*))";

        NamingEnumeration results = dctx.search(base, filter, sc);
        LdapUserDetails user = new LdapUserDetails();
        while (results.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();
            Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

            user.setCn(getAttribute(attrs, "cn"));
            user.setFullName(getAttribute(attrs, "fullName"));
            user.setMail(getAttribute(attrs, "mail"));
            user.setMobile(getAttribute(attrs, "mobile"));
            user.setLocation(getAttribute(attrs, "l")); 
        }
        dctx.close();
        return user;
        }
```

Pl. Help me to solve the issues

1. I didn't mention the authentication as simple. From where i am getting **type=simple** in log file
2. Why I am getting dn=""

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default authentication is "simple Bind" which means a DN and a password.
You are not setting any credentials in the Environment `env`, so JNDI does the default of trying to do a Bind anonymous, i.e. empty DN and password.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Ludovic Poitou. I am new to LDAP. If I add env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none"); Is this code will solve the error

Comment: No, because this will continue to do unauthenticated requests (i.e empty DN) which will continue to be rejected.

Comment: Is it mandatory to give authentication type as simple. If it is none we don't need to give the code in security.xml <property name="userDn" value="cn=userid,o=company,ou=groups"/> <property name="password" value="password"/>. Is it right